# Java generic function: how to return Generic type

Tags: java, generics

Here's a Java generic pattern:

```
public <T> T getResultData(Class<T> resultClass, other_args) { 
   ...
   return resultClass.cast(T-thing);
}
```

A typical call looks like:

```
   DoubleBuffer buffer;
   buffer = thing.getResultData(DoubleBuffer.class, args);
```

I've never been able to figure out how to use this pattern cleanly when the desired return type is, itself, generic. To be 'concrete', what if a function like this wants to return `Map<String,String>`? Since you can't get a class object for a generic, of course, the only option would be to pass `Map.class`, and then you need a cast and an `@SuppressWarning` after all.

One ends up with a call like:

```
Map<String, String> returnedMap;
returnedMap = thing.getResultData(Map.class, some_other_args);
```

Now one is back to needing casts and suppressing a warning.

I suppose that one could take something from the `java.lang.reflect.Type` family instead of the `Class`, but those aren't especially easy to concoct. That looks like:

```
class Dummy {
 Map<String, String> field;
}

...

Type typeObject = Dummy.class.getField("field").getGenericType();
```

Given this, the called function could extract the base type and use that for casting or newInstance-ing, but the dummy field business sure looks ugly.

Note that functions like this are not always calling `newInstance`. Obviously, if they do, they don't need to call `resultClass.cast`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot do that in the standard Java API. However, there are utility classes available which can get the [`Type`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) out of a generic class. In for example Google Gson (which converts JSON to fullworthy Javabeans and vice versa) there's a [`TypeToken`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.1.1/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) class. You can use it as follows:

```
List<Person> persons = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Person>>() {}.getType());
```

Such a construct is exactly what you need. You can find [here](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.java) the source sode, you may find it useful as well. It only requires an additional `getResultData()` method which can accept a `Type`.

Answer (score 2):

Well,. here's an ugly (partial) solution. You can't generically paramaterize a generic param, so you can't write

```
public <T<U,V>> T getResultData ...
```

but you can return a parameterized collection, e.g. for a set

```
public < T extends Set< U >, U > T getResultData( Class< T > resultClass, Class< U > paramClass ) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        return resultClass.newInstance();
    }
```

where you could get rid of the U-param if it existed in the class signature.

Comment: Interesting, and it will work for two parameters as well (by extending `Map`). But, honestly, choosing between this and `@SuppressWarnings` I'd take the latter every time :-)

Comment: I agree - I did say "ugly" ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yeah I don't think this is possible.

Imagine this scenario.  You have a file with a serialized object that you want to read it. If you make the function generic, you'll be able to use it without a cast.  But lets say you have a Map serialized into a file.

When you deserialize it, there's **no way to know** what the original generic map type was.  As far as java is concerned, it's just a Map

I ran into this with lists, and it was annoying.  But what I actually ended up doing was creating a generic "converting collection" class that takes a collection and a "converter" (which can be an anonymous inner type).

Then when you iterate through the converting collection, every item gets cast.  And that solved the warning problem. It's a lot of work just to get rid of the warning, but I don't think that was the main reason I came up with that framework. You can also do more powerful things like take a collection of filenames, and then write a converter that loads the data in the file, or does a query, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TypeLiteral](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/type-literals.html) if you want to use typesafe container classes. They are used in [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) to provide typesafe bindings. See Guice Source code for more examples and [TypeLiteral](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html) class.

By the way, ou don't need cast, if you call `resultClass.newInstance()` for instance.

```
public <T> T getResultData(Class<T> resultClass, other_args) {       
   ...
   return resultClass.newInstance();
}
```

Comment: Except you can't obtain and thus pass Class instance for generic class like `Map<String, String>` so this won't help at all with OP's question.

Comment: Yup. That's exactly how we got here.

Comment: They are not supported in the Language but you use TypeLiteral, invented by Neal Gafter. http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/type-literals.html

Comment: I'd upvote the TypeLiteral reference if you edited it into your actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understood correctly what you really trying to do is (illegal pseudo-syntax):

```
public <T, S, V> T<S, V> getResultData(Class<T<S, V>> resultClass, other_args) { 
  ...
  return resultClass.cast(T-thing);
}
```

You can't because you can't further parameterize generic type `T`. Messing about with `java.lang.reflect.*` won't help:

1. There is no such thing as `Class<Map<String, String>>` and thus no way to dynamically create its instance.
2. There is no way to actually **declare** the method in question as returning `T<S, V>`

Comment: @ChssPly76: As it happens, there is a GenericType object for Map<String, String>. If you have a field of type Map<String, String>, and you call Field.getGenericType, you will get it. However, about the only way to acquire one of those is, indeed, to get it from reflection on a field or return type.

Comment: You mean `ParameterizedType`. Yes, there is and yes, you can obtain it from field / method declaration. And no, it's **not** the same as `Class` and thus will **not** help you in any way: you can't cast to it and you can't create an instance of corresponding class using just `ParameterizedType` either.

Comment: Well, actually, this isn't as impossible as it looks. The called function can call getRawType() on a ParameterizedType for newInstance/cast purposes. It's just ugly, but it looks like that's as good as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't really need the exact generic type of the map and your code does not rely on that type but you're simply annoyed by the warnings you could write:

```
Map<?, ?> returnedMap;
returnedMap = thing.getResultData(Map.class, some_other_args);
```

then you can use any of the map methods that are not type-parametrized like containsKey, clear, iterator and so on or iterate over the entrySet or pass returnedMap to any generic method and everything will be type safe.

```
Map<?, ?> returnedMap;
returnedMap = thing.getResultData(Map.class, some_other_args);

Object myKey = ...;

Object someValue = returnedMap.get(myKey);

for (Iterator<? extends Map.Entry<?,?>> it = returnedMap.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
  if (it.next().equals(myKey))
    it.remove();

for (Map.Entry<?,?> e : returnedMap.entrySet()) {
  if (e.getKey().equals(myKey))
    e.setValue(null); // if the map supports null values
}

doSomething(returnedMap);

...

<K,V> void doSomething(Map<K,V> map) { ... }
```

there is actually many things that you can do with a Map in a type-safe manner without knowing its key or value type.