# Generics: Creating parameterized class argument

Tags: java, generics, arguments

How does one get a parameterized Class object to be used as a method argument?

```
class A<T>
{
    public A(Class<T> c)
    {
    }

    void main()
    {
        A<String> a1 = new A<String>(String.class);     // OK
        A<List<String>> a2 = new A<List<String>>(List<String>.class);  // error
        A<List<String>> a3 = new A<List<String>>(Class<List<String>>);  // error
    }
}
```

Why do I want to do that, you may ask?  I have a parameterized class whose type is another parameterized class, and whose constructor requires that other class type as an argument.  I understand that runtime classes have no information on their type parameters, but that shouldn't prevent me from doing this at compile time.  It seems that I should be able to specify a type such as `List<String>.class`.  Is there another syntax to do this?

Here is my real usage case:

```
public class Bunch<B>
{
    Class<B> type;

    public Bunch(Class<B> type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public static class MyBunch<M> extends Bunch<List<M>>
    {
        Class<M> individualType;

        // This constructor has redundant information.
        public MyBunch(Class<M> individualType, Class<List<M>> listType)
        {
            super(listType);
            this.individualType = individualType;
        }

        // I would prefer this constructor.
        public MyBunch(Class<M> individualType)
        {
            super( /* What do I put here? */ );
            this.individualType = individualType;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Have a look at Google Gson's `TypeToken` http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html. It's open source and it solves the same problem you're having.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java generic function: how to return Generic type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959022/java-generic-function-how-to-return-generic-type)

Comment: Thank you, BalusC.  Firstly, I'm comforted that I'm not missing something simple.  But I'm not ready to bite this off, because dealing with **Type**s instead of **Class**es in my application looks difficult.

Answer (score 0):

How about just cast?

```
super((Class<List<M>>)List.class);
```

Class literals are not going to have the type parameters that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Remember you will NOT get a List as a class in runtime, and the right approach would probably be using TypeToken as BalusC told you. Without TypeToken, you can't cast to List, but you can create something like this:

```
public static class MyBunch2<List_M extends List<M>, M> extends Bunch<List_M>
{
    Class<M> individualType;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public MyBunch2(Class<M> individualType)
    {
        super((Class<List_M>) List.class);
        this.individualType = individualType;
    }
}
```

Since `List_M extends List<M>` this is not as typesafe as you may wish, but maybe is nice enough. Creating an instance will be as ugly as writing

```
MyBunch2<List<String>, String> a = new MyBunch2<List<String>, String>(String.class);
```

but you can improve it with a factory method

```
public static <M2> MyBunch2<List<M2>, M2> of(Class<M2> individualType){
    return new MyBunch2<List<M2>, M2>(individualType);
}
```

and then write

```
MyBunch2<List<String>, String> b = MyBunch2.of(String.class);
```

If you are using eclipse, code assist will help you writing the ugly class MyBunch2, String>

Of course, in runtime, this.type will be java.util.List, not java.util.List
To get it right, go for TypeToken.

---Continuation---

You can even make another class

```
public static class MyBunch3<M> extends MyBunch2<List<M>, M>
{
        public MyBunch3(Class<M> individualType) {
            super(individualType);
        }
}
```

And then create instances as

```
MyBunch3<String> c = new MyBunch3<String>(String.class);
```

There must be a way to do that in just one class...but I can't figure it out